# What's the alternative to storing plain-text passwords in a MySQL Database?

Tags: passwords, mysql, node.js

What's the alternative to storing plain-text passwords in a Database?

For example, I'm using Node.js to get a POST request for signing up / logging in a user from a webpage.

When signing up a user, I get the parameters for the email and password from the request, and query it through the (Node.js) server. It then stores the data in SQL.

What's a way to *not* store plain-text passwords in the database? (because people recommend it but don't explain the alternative)

Edit: I already know about SQL injection, so I check the request data in the server.

Comment: Store a cryptographically secure hash only that is not reversible to the password itself.  Then when you want to test a password to see if it matches, you hash it the same way and compare the hashes.  This way you never store the actual password.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there any link (for an article) on how to do that?

Comment: @ParkingMaster Look into using Argon2, scrypt, or bcrypt for password hashing. Do **NOT** store just a hash of the password using a fast hash like SHA-1 or even SHA-512! Although that's better than storing it in plaintext, hashes can be guessed far, far faster than a slow KDF like Argon2.

Comment: There are hundreds of articles on the web.  Here's one: https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/password-hashing-with-nodejs/.

Comment: @jfriend00 Simply hashing a password (even salted) is a bad idea. I don't think you should suggest that without elaborating on the caveats. The example you link uses PBKDF2 which is a pretty good KDF, but the values in that example (1000 iterations) is way too low. That's half of the minimum recommended value from 20 years ago.

Comment: @forest - Take a look at the techniques in the article I linked to.  What's wrong with that?  It's using `crypto.pbkdf2` in the nodejs crypto library.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because it is using 1000 iterations which is not nearly enough, not to mention PBKDF2 is quickly becoming obsolete as it is not memory-hard. Maybe 20,000 iterations would be acceptable, but if NodeJS has Argon2 or even bcrypt in its crypto library, that would be superior.

Comment: Then, would you kindly make a more specific suggestion about what the OP should do.  So, far all you've done is poke holes in other suggestions and not made any concrete suggestion that shows actual code that the OP can use in nodejs.

Comment: @jfriend00 My suggestion was to use Argon2, but I don't know enough NodeJS to provide an example. I think the resource you linked is fine, but it should be told with the caveat that 1000-iteration PBKDF2 as shown in the example code is not enough. Maybe https://npm.io/search/keyword:argon2 has something?

Comment: So the best I can find right now is https://npm.io/package/argon2, which is in the npm repository and will do better than the NodeJS crypto library.

Comment: @forest - That argon2 module requires native code be compiled, so it not based on built-in nodejs crypto.  It may work fine (I have no idea), but something that uses built-in crypto libraries would generally be preferred and may simplify deployment and upgrades unless you have some reason that none of the built-in crypto options are sufficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 In that case then PBKDF2 with the built-in crypto would probably be fine (it is not memory-hard which is a huge weakness, but it is still far better than storing passwords in plaintext) as long as the iteration count is high enough. The example setting in that link of 1000 however is too little.

Comment: OP, I think this is what you are looking for:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/password_hash

Comment: @mti2935 once again thanks, this really helps :)

Comment: @ParkingMaster No problem.  BTW, cool game - https://parkingmaster.w3spaces.com/

Comment: @mti2935 Thanks! By the way, is there a github link for the details on https://www.npmjs.com/package/password_hash?

Comment: @ParkingMaster I don't code in node.js, so I don't know.  But, PHP has a built-in function `password_hash()` that is used extensively for password salting and hashing in part because it is future tolerant and backwards compatible.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords.  When I saw your question, it occurred to me that a function like this in node.js is exactly what you need, and a quick Google search lead me to the page that I posted above.  I hope this helps.